# iOS - Dynamic onClick function for uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, onclick

I have no problem creating an `on click` event within `UITableview` using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, the problem is that I would rather set up the `on click` event while also setting up the cell, since not every cell is going to need an `on click` event, and they will work differently depending which cell it is. Is there a way to set an on click to specifically the detail text? Maybe create an overlaying invisible frame perfectly matched to the text?

If this isn't doable, I'll just do it the long way, but that's going to be a lot of code.

If I need to expound upon my problem, please just let me know if I'm being confusing at all. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use prototype cells?

Comment: I'm using prototype cells for my slide menu, but I'm not familiar with their usage in other contexts. This is only my second app.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event to a button in the cell you want it to and format it like the label.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickDescription:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then in the code:

```
-(void)onClickDescription { 
     CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.yourTableView];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.yourTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        //Do what you need
    }
}
```

To customise:

1. In Storyboard use "custom cell" add a label and a button and tag 1    and 2.
2. In viewForCellAtIndexPath just put:

   `UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];`
   `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];`
3. Now you can format however you feel like formating

   `label.font = ....`
   `label.textColor = ....`

Comment: That could work. Formatting it to look just like detailText might be a challenge though.

Comment: No very easy. I will amend response.

Comment: So does this specific code going to give me the ability to just do this to one cell at a time? My content is dynamic, a table could have one, two, or zero links but five cells. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you always have 5 cells then you don't need any code or button. You just build a static table with 5 cells in storyboard and have 5 segues in lieu of links. If they all segue to the same viewController with different content you can use a switch statement in prepareForSegue.

Comment: I wish it were that simple. Sometimes it's five, sometimes it is two. The app is for a conference and the information displayed in the tables will change frequently.

Comment: Where do you get the information to display? And what does it do when you click on the different cells?

Comment: Sorry, got distracted building the android version. There are text files sitting on a web server. The app needs to be able to update quickly (not through the iTunes store).